# How to use symbols of extended ASCII table in C?

Tags: c, character, ascii, extended-ascii

I've been tried to print ***Extended ASCII characters***:

[http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/](http://fsymbols.com/images/ascii.png)

But all those symbols were printed as *question*-character on the white background **`?`**.

I use the following cycle to print that symbols:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    printf("%c", 201);
```

**Question:** Is there any way to print those ***Extended ASCII characters*** or not? Or maybe there is special library for these characters?

---

OS Linux Ubuntu 13.04, Code::Blocks 12.11 IDE.

Comment: Extensions to ASCII are non-standard and best avoided.

Comment: Do you want say that I have to avoid them?

Comment: hopefully a well configured terminal and ncurses will help. Emitting output depends on the terminal. WHat are you using? A PC ? A linux box with xterm ?

Comment: @BigMike, So, the program prints that characters, but my terminal doesn't recognize them?

Comment: You don't *have* to avoid extended ASCII, but if you don't then you can expect a lot of problems with portability etc.

Comment: @PaulR, Uh.. Understood.

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy if you're on unix/linux, it depends also on the terminal you're using (Xterm or RXVT or VT100). If you're on DOS IIRC there was a device driver to manage such ascii exception. on Win32 honestly I don't know

Comment: I tried some chars and heard a beeping from speaker.

Comment: The loop is not using `i`, it's printing codepoint 201 31 times.

Comment: @unwind, It uses. I want to print a bold line above and under matrix in order to make it easier to find in the output.

Comment: There is no “extended ASCII”. ASCII is an 7-bit encoding, which is represented in modern devices and protocols using 8-bit bytes with first bit set to zero. Any reference to “extended ASCII” should be read as “a misnomer for someone’s 8-bit character code, which is purported to coincide with ASCII in the first 128 positions”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I've got it. The answer suggests me to use Unicode - that is solution. Thanks for the information) I always glad for getting more knowledge.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's better to use unicode than extended ASCII, which is non-standard. A thread about printing unicode characters in C :
[printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals)

But indeed you need to copy paste unicode characters..

A better way to start:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("\u2500\u2501\n");
}
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode for unicode characters for this extended ASCII style box art..