# How to use extended ascii characters in C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application, extended-ascii

I cant seem to find a general explanation for how to use extended ascii characters. I am specifically trying to use the different pipe variations for a minimap in my roguelike game.

```
    static Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    string shown = e.GetString(new byte[] { 185 });
```

This code displays "1" even though all of the extended ascii tables show the pipe going in the top, left, bottom directions. Please help!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the result?

Comment: Looking at [ISO_8859-1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1), 185d (0xB9) is actually the symbol ¹. So your output is what I would expect.

Comment: You can also just hard code them: `Console.WriteLine("╔═╗"); Console.WriteLine("╚═╝");` which makes the code easy to read. Or use constants if that's easier: `private const char TopLeft = '╔';`

Comment: Also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362509/how-to-use-symbols-of-extended-ascii-table-in-c

Comment: Thank you Rufus L! It is as simple as copy and pasting the characters from the wiki page to my program. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You shoud change your `Console.OutputEncoding`:

```
Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
Console.OutputEncoding = e;
```

then `Console.WriteLine(shown);` should display the desired result.