# Why can't I print the decimal value of a extended ASCII char like 'Ç'? in C

Tags: c, ascii, extended-ascii

First, in this C project we have some conditions as far as writing code: I can´t declare a variable and attribute a value to it on the same line of code and we are only allowed to use while loops. Also, I'm using Ubuntu for reference.

I want to print the decimal ASCII value, character by character, of a string passed to the program. For e.g. if the input is "rose", the program correctly prints 114 111 115 101. But when I try to print the decimal value of a char like a 'Ç', the first char of the extended ASCII table, the program weirdly prints -61 -121. Here is the code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{  
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        while (argv[1][i] != '\0')
        {
            printf ("%i ", argv[1][i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I did some research and found that i should try **unsigned char argv** instead of char, like this:

```
int main (int argc, unsigned char **argv)
{  
    int i;

    i = 0; 
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        while (argv[1][i] != '\0')
        {
            printf("%i ", argv[1][i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I run the program with a 'Ç' and the output is 195 135 (still wrong).

How can I make this program print the right ASCII decimal value of a char from the extended ASSCCI table, in this case a **"Ç" should be a 128.**

Thank you!!

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, using an unsigned vs. signed octet type matters not to `printf` anyway. A better idea is to handle Unicode in C properly: https://linuxhint.com/unicode-c/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use symbols of extended ASCII table in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362509/how-to-use-symbols-of-extended-ascii-table-in-c)

Comment: I *strongly* suggest you read [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and immediately forget that the term "extended ASCII" exist. It doesn't mean what you think it means and avoiding it in place of the proper terminology (for example a specific encoding) will only ever increase understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Your platform is using UTF-8 Encoding.

Unicode Latin Capital Letter C with Cedilla (U+00C7) "Ç" encodes to 0xC3 0x87 in UTF-8.

In turn those bytes in decimal are 195 and 135 which you see in output.

Remember UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding for characters outside basic ASCII (0 thru 127).
That character is code-point 128 in extended ASCII but UTF-8 diverges from Extend ASCII in that range.

You may find there's tools on your platform to convert that to extended ASCII but I suspect you don't want to do that and should work with the encoding supported by your platform (which I am sure is UTF-8).

It's Unicode Code Point 199 so unless you have a specific application for Extended ASCII you'll probably just make things worse by converting to it. That's not least because it's a much smaller set of characters than Unicode.

Here's some information for Unicode Latin Capital Letter C with Cedilla including the UTF-8 Encoding: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00C7/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of representing non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters, such as `Ç`.  Your question suggests you're familiar with 8-bit character sets such as [ISO-8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859), where in several of its variants `Ç` does indeed have code 199.  (That is, if your computer were set up to use ISO-8859, your program probably would have worked, although it might have printed -57 instead of 199.)

But these days, more and more systems use [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), which they typically encode using a particular *multibyte* encoding, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

In C, one way to extract *wide characters* from a *multibyte character string* is the function [`mbtowc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mbtowc).  Here is a modification of your program, using this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{  
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        char *p = argv[1];
        int n;
        wchar_t wc;
        while((n = mbtowc(&wc, p, strlen(p))) > 0)
        {
            printf ("%lc: %d (%d)\n", wc, wc, n);
            p += n;
        }
    }
}
```

You give `mbtowc` a pointer to the multibyte encoding of one or more multibyte characters, and it converts one of them, returning it via its first argument — here, into the variable `wc`.  It returns the number of multibyte characters it used, or 0 if it encountered the end of the string.

When I run this program on the string `abÇd`, it prints

```
a: 97 (1)
b: 98 (1)
Ç: 199 (2)
d: 100 (1)
```

This shows that in Unicode (just like [8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)), `Ç` has the code 199, but it takes two bytes to encode it.

Under Linux, at least, the C library supports potentially multiple multibyte encodings, not just UTF-8.  It decides which encoding to use based on the current "locale", which is usually part fo the environment, literally governed by an environment variable such as `$LANG`.  That's what the call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` is for: it tells the C library to pay attention to the environment to select a locale for the program's functions, like `mbtowc`, to use.

Unicode is of course *huge*, encoding thousands and thousands of characters.  Here's the output of the modified version of your program on the string "abΣ∫":

```
a: 97 (1)
b: 98 (1)
Σ: 931 (2)
∫: 8747 (3)
: 128522 (4)
```

Emoji like  typically take four bytes to encode in UTF-8.