# Why are my utf-8 characters not displaying?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, utf-8

I am having an issue where on linux my characters like łąćźżó are not displayed correctly (like (TM)`~řÉ), but on windows they are, with the same code.

```
int main()
{ 
    printf("łąć");
    return 0;
}
```

this displays correctly when compiled on windows but not on linux, but I even added the utf-8 options and saved all files as UTF-8 encoding :(

Makefile flags only + link:

```
COMPILE_FLAGS = -std=c++0x -m32 -fPIC -c -finput-charset=UTF-8 -finput-charset=UTF-8 -fwide-exec-charset=UTF-8 -I ./ -w -D LINUX -D PROJECT_NAME=\"SampCaptcha\"

SampCaptcha = -D SampCaptcha $(COMPILE_FLAGS)

$(GPP) -m32 -lrt -ldl -fshort-wchar -shared -o $(SampCaptcha_OUTFILE) *.o
```

Why is this not working? the text is unreadable to users this way.

Alright, so people are asking for the 1:1 input/output, here you go:

Output on linux:
[image]

and this is the text:

```
Message("Witaj nowy graczu!");
Message("Wygląda na to iż Twoje ip nie jest nam znane");
Message("Za chwilkę zostaniesz przekierowany na serwer i będzies spokojnie mógł grać z innymi");
Message("Zanim to jednak zrobimy, pierwszę sprawdzimy czy nie jesteś komputerem który chce zepsuć serwer");
Message("Proszę się zrespawnować aby kontynuować");
```

And like I said, when compiled as a DLL it works on Windows, when inputting directly commands into the host program with unicode characters they are displayed on the chat. (it's a closed source application anyway to which I don't have access, but we are sure it's my GCC doing something wrong, many other people seem to have no problems with displaying special characters)

output of locale:

```
~# locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Don't have much experience working with UTF-8 but found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals) Seems to be along the same lines of your question so hope that helps.

Comment: what's your output on linux?

Comment: hm already a downvote, seems like migrating from windows to linux won't be an option -.-'

Comment: Maybe your `Message()` function is doing something wrong? I can't reproduce it, prints correctly with `printf()` on my ubuntu machine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgSVf.png

Comment: hm I will consult the people that created the software in that case, I thought it was my G++/GCC.

Comment: Is your terminal capable of UTF-8 output? What happens if you `cat yourfilename.c`? Also show the output of `locale` command.

Comment: Also before blaming gcc or Linux try a [known good system](http://ideone.com/1ZJc1m).

Comment: when I `cat GameMode.cpp` I get to see the file which has the correct characters.

Comment: @n.m. that known good system has been configured by people who know how GCC works on all fronts and work on a dayly basis with it

Comment: Your system is configured correctly out of the box. You may want to (1) remove the -fwide-exec-charset option (it is wrong to set it to UTF-8, it should be UTF-32 which is the default anyway) and (2) at the start of the program, call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` which you should do in most programs anyway, but these should not affect the result of this particular prrogram. What terminal are you using? What happens if you do `printf '\xc5\x81\xc5\x82\n'` in the terminaal?