# Printf and japanese wide char returns -1 instead of printing it?

Tags: c, encoding, printf

Why does

`printf("%s", "米");` outputs `米` and returns `3`, but

`printf("%ls", L"米");` prints nothing and returns `-1` ?

I'm confused here.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I type 'gcc', but since I run OSX 10.9, I think it's clang by default now

Comment: As this thread suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals , in order to use the wide character notation (`L""` along with `%ls`) the locale has to be set correctly.

Comment: Ok i feel dumb now. Thank you sir !

Comment: For the first: If the text is stored as UTF8 in your *source*, all that `printf` does is send the literal 3 bytes to the console. Then your *console* interprets the UTF8 sequence again, and shows the correct character.

Comment: there are versions of printf just for printing wide characters.  for instance:  'wprintf()'  the code should use those facilities for printing wide characters.