# Printing Greek characters in C

Tags: c, unicode, character, non-english

Is there any way to print Greek characters in C?
I'm trying to print out the word "ΑΝΑΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΙΣΜΟΣ"
with:

```
printf("ΑΝΑΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΙΣΜΟΣ");
```

but I get some random symbols as output in the console.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals

Comment: Essential reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Programmer Should Know About Unicode ad Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your console font to a Unicode TrueType font and emit the data using an "ANSI" mechanism (that's assuming Windows... ). For example this code prints γειά σου:

```
#include "windows.h"

int main() 
{
     SetConsoleOutputCP(1253); //"ANSI" Greek
     printf("\xE3\xE5\xE9\xDC \xF3\xEF\xF5"); // encoded as windows-1253

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a console that supports Unicode, like [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)
2. Use [wprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) or similar functions
3. Always use Unicode :)