# Print greek characters in CLion IDE

Tags: c, utf-8, printf, clion

OS  - Windows 8.1

IDE - CLion 2021.3.2

I need to print some greek characters but what I have is these symbols: ╬╗ , ╬╝ , ¤ü

[image]

What am I doing wrong? This is my settings for file encodings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unicode requires support by the output terminal as well...

Comment: I set my console's encoding to UTF-8 but it still does not work... some advice?

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (examples in Python): `'λ μ ρ'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp850')` returns `'╬╗ ╬╝ ¤ü'` and vice versa: `"╬╗ ╬╝ ¤ü".encode( 'cp850').decode( 'utf-8')` yields `'λ μ ρ'`. Sorry, I don't know _CLion_…

Comment: "OS - Windows 8.1". SO is chock-full of questions of this sort ("help me display characters of language X") and like 99.9% of them are from Windows users. Perhaps just switch to a more friendly OS? Or if this doesn't work, maybe try [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/encoding.html#console).

Comment: `printf` sends bytes to the terminal.  Save your source file in UTF-8 and the bytes sent will be UTF-8.  I don't use that IDE but that may help Being Windows it may help to save the source as UTF-8 w/ BOM as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and advices, but I solved installing an old version of CLion.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: UTF-8 does not have, or need, a BOM.

Comment: @DevSolar While UTF8 doesn’t need a “byte order mark” the Unicode code point for BOM can be used as a signature to indicate UTF-8 and some Windows editors assume a legacy encoding such as Windows-1252 unless that BOM is present or UTF-8 is specifically selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved installing an old version of Clion (v 2021.1.3) default settings.

[image]

Others tentatives changing that not worked:

1. I had tried to reset the default settings in Clion v  2021.3.2
2. `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` but I needed to change c standard from C99-->C90 in *CMakeLists.txt* to work

Regarding the negative score, maybe it was a banal question, but I tried to solve it from a week unsuccessfully. I am not an expert in the language C or in computer science in general, and I just did not have others to ask how to solve my problem, thus I have only wanted some help.

Answer (score 0):

Set your console font to a Unicode TrueType font and emit the data using an "ANSI" mechanism.
For example this code prints γειά σου:

```
#include "windows.h"

int main() 
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1253); //"ANSI" Greek
    printf("\xE3\xE5\xE9\xDC \xF3\xEF\xF5"); // encoded as windows-1253

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried the answer of @Noam M [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265065/printing-greek-characters-in-c) but it was not quite what I wanted as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

While you work on CLion open the file in notepad++ then menu Encoding - Encoding in ANSI, and save. In your open CLion you will see that the file was loaded in a wrong encoding:'UTF-8'. Click on reload in 'windows-1253' and you 'll be OK.[CLion reload in windows 1253](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IE0O.jpg)