# The width specifier in printf does not work properly with accented characters

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to format output of some strings in c with the width specifier and the printf-function. However I'm having trouble getting the behaviour I want. It seems that everytime printf encounters the character å, ä or ö the the width reserved for the string gets one position smaller.

A code-snippet to illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf(">%-10s<\n", "aoa");
  printf(">%-10s<\n", "aäoa");
  printf(">%-10s<\n", "aäoöa");
  printf(">%-10s<\n", "aäoöaå");

  return 0;
}
```

Outputs in my ubuntu linux bash-shell.

```
>aoa       <
>aäoa     <
>aäoöa   <
>aäoöaå <
```

I'm looking for advice on how to deal with this. What I want is for all the strings in the snippet above to print within space-padded 10 char wide field like so:

```
>aoa       <
>aäoa      <
>aäoöa     <
>aäoöaå    <
```

I also appreciate any insight as to why this is happening or feedback if this is not an issue with other setups.

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 encoding? Those characters require 2 bytes, and `printf` might not be UTF-8 aware.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals

Comment: @user694733 Yes, I was using utf-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why this is happening?

Take a look to [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

As an alternative to wide chars and under UTF8, you can use this function to count the number of non-ASCII chars, then, you can add the result to the width specifier of `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(const char *str)
{
    int len = 0;

    while (*str != '\0') {
        if ((*str & 0xc0) == 0x80) {
            len++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf(">%-*s<\n", 10 + func("aoa"), "aoa");
    printf(">%-*s<\n", 10 + func("aäoa"), "aäoa");
    printf(">%-*s<\n", 10 + func("aäoöa"), "aäoöa");
    printf(">%-*s<\n", 10 + func("aäoöaå"), "aäoöaå");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>aoa       <
>aäoa      <
>aäoöa     <
>aäoöaå    <
```

Comment: Even though I suppose using wprintf is more reasonable in the long run I ended up using your suggestion. The link was gold. Marking this as accepted.

Comment: Note that this method only works with characters whose display width is 1.

Comment: @Cyker, you are right, but this is more related with the fonts of the terminal, even using wide chars: `wprintf(L">%-10ls<\n", L"aäoöa包");` the output is not aligned with the other lines.

Comment: @KeineLust Almost all fonts display CJK chars in double-width. Beyond those chars, there are symbols that are displayed in either single- or double-width, depending on the font used. I actually had similar problem and considered this method until I needed to handle CJK chars. But OP asked for accented chars. I'm no language expert but I think probably they are single-width in all major languages.

Answer (score 7):

Use wide character strings and `wprintf`:

```
#include <cwchar>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
  // seems to be needed for the correct output encoding
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  wprintf(L">%-10ls<\n", L"aoa");
  wprintf(L">%-10ls<\n", L"aäoa");
  wprintf(L">%-10ls<\n", L"aäoöa");
  wprintf(L">%-10ls<\n", L"aäoöaå");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used literal strings in the example to keep it brief. In my actual problem I'm getting the strings from a struct. I suppose I'd have to convert these strings to wide character-strings with [mbstowcs()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mbstowcs) or something? I mean I obviously can't do `wprintf(L">%-10ls<\n", Lsome->member);`

Answer (score 3):

[Alter Mann's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35427865/1475978) is along the correct lines, except that one should not just hardcode a custom function to count the number of bytes in a multibyte string that do not encode to a visible character: You should localize the code with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` or similar, and `strlen(str) - mbstowcs(NULL, str, 0)` to count the number of bytes in the string that do not encode a visible character.

[`setlocale()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) is standard C (C89, C99, C11), but also defined in POSIX.1. [`mbstowcs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html) is standard C99 and C11, and also defined in POSIX.1. Both are also implemented in Microsoft C libraries, so they do work basically everywhere.

Consider the following example program, that prints C strings specified on the command line:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Counts the number of (visible) characters in a string */
static size_t ms_len(const char *const ms)
{
    if (ms)
        return mbstowcs(NULL, ms, 0);
    else
        return 0;
}

/* Number of bytes that do not generate a visible character in a string */
static size_t ms_extras(const char *const ms)
{
    if (ms)
        return strlen(ms) - mbstowcs(NULL, ms, 0);
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg;

    /* Default locale */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++)
        printf(">%-*s< (%zu bytes; %zu chars; %zu bytes extra in wide chars)\n",
               (int)(10 + ms_extras(argv[arg])), argv[arg],
               strlen(argv[arg]), ms_len(argv[arg]), ms_extras(argv[arg]));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you compile the above to `example`, and you run

```
./example aaa aaä aää äää aa€ a€€ €€€ a ä €
```

the program will output

```
>aaa       < (3 bytes; 3 chars; 0 bytes extra in wide chars)
>aaä       < (4 bytes; 3 chars; 1 bytes extra in wide chars)
>aää       < (5 bytes; 3 chars; 2 bytes extra in wide chars)
>äää       < (6 bytes; 3 chars; 3 bytes extra in wide chars)
>aa€       < (5 bytes; 3 chars; 2 bytes extra in wide chars)
>a€€       < (7 bytes; 3 chars; 4 bytes extra in wide chars)
>€€€       < (9 bytes; 3 chars; 6 bytes extra in wide chars)
>a         < (1 bytes; 1 chars; 0 bytes extra in wide chars)
>ä         < (2 bytes; 1 chars; 1 bytes extra in wide chars)
>€         < (3 bytes; 1 chars; 2 bytes extra in wide chars)
>         < (4 bytes; 1 chars; 3 bytes extra in wide chars)
```

If the last `<` does not line up with the others, it is because the font used is not accurately fixed-width: the emoticon  is wider than normal characters like `Ä`, that's all. Blame the font.

The last character is U+1F608 SMILING FACE WITH HORNS, from the [Emoticons unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29), in case your OS/browser/font cannot display it. In Linux, all the above `>` and `<` line up correctly in all terminals I have, including in the console (non-graphical system console), although the console font does not have the glyph for the emoticon, and instead just shows it as a diamond.

Unlike [Alter Mann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35427865/1475978), this approach is portable, and makes no assumptions about what character set is actually used by the current user.

Comment: Nice answer, you are absolutely right about portability,  my function assumes UTF8.