# Print ASCII box not working

Tags: c, windows, ascii, mingw32

I am just trying to print a shape filled with filled ASCII boxes into the console, but the output is just garbage text. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char shade_block[] = {
    "▒▒██████▒▒\n\
     ▒████████▒\n\
     ██████████\n\
     ▒████████▒\n\
     ▒▒██████▒▒\n\
    "};

int main()
{
    printf(shade_block);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
ΓûÆΓûÆΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûÆΓûÆ
         ΓûÆΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûÆ
         ΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûê
         ΓûÆΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûÆ
         ΓûÆΓûÆΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûêΓûÆΓûÆ
```

Picture of the code, if it's not displaying properly.

[image: Picture of the code, if it's not displaying properly.]

I am working in C, CodeLite IDE, WIndows 10 with MinGW-32. Thanks in advance.

Comment: result depend from code page used by console. usual console use OEM code page, when you ANSI code page. you need use Unicode functions and text for correct print

Comment: Note that you should not use ```\``` termination to create long strings — witness the spaces on the second and subsequent lines.  Use string concatenation: `"▒▒██████▒▒\n"
     "▒████████▒\n"
     "██████████\n"
     "▒████████▒\n"
     "▒▒██████▒▒\n"` which deals with the leading  blanks too.  There's just white space (newlines in your code, blanks in my comment) between the string segments.  The backslash-newline mechanism was necessary before C90, but not since then.

Comment: It probably isn't any consolation to tell you that the code works OK on a Mac running macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though RbMm and PeterJ's answers worked, I used tips from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals) StackOVerflow question and eventually figured out how to print the block as-is without any character-escaping or WriteConsoleW:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>              //For wprintf and wide chars
#include <io.h>                 //For _setmode
#define U_16 0x20000            //U-16 text mode, for the text blocks

const wchar_t shade_block[] = {
    L"▒▒██████▒▒\n"
    "▒████████▒\n"
    "██████████\n"
    "▒████████▒\n"
    "▒▒██████▒▒\n"
    };

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), U_16); //set the output mode to U_16
    wprintf(L"%s\n", shade_block);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How your text editor codes unprintable characters is unknown but I guess it is UTF-something, and yout table contains something completely different that you think
2. See how do ascii > 127 print

   ```
   for(int i = 32; i < 256;i++)
       printf("%3d / %02x = %c\n\r", i, i, i);`
   ```

Then define your table using escape sequences - for example

```
char a[] = "\xf3\xef"
```

Here you have 4 columns version

```
for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++)
    printf("%3d / %02x = %c%s", i, i, i, ((i >> 2) << 2 == i) ? "\n\r" : "\t");
```

and the output should be like this:

```
 32 / 20 =
 33 / 21 = !     34 / 22 = "     35 / 23 = #     36 / 24 = $
 37 / 25 = %     38 / 26 = &     39 / 27 = '     40 / 28 = (
 41 / 29 = )     42 / 2a = *     43 / 2b = +     44 / 2c = ,
 45 / 2d = -     46 / 2e = .     47 / 2f = /     48 / 30 = 0
 49 / 31 = 1     50 / 32 = 2     51 / 33 = 3     52 / 34 = 4
 53 / 35 = 5     54 / 36 = 6     55 / 37 = 7     56 / 38 = 8
 57 / 39 = 9     58 / 3a = :     59 / 3b = ;     60 / 3c = <
 61 / 3d = =     62 / 3e = >     63 / 3f = ?     64 / 40 = @
 65 / 41 = A     66 / 42 = B     67 / 43 = C     68 / 44 = D
 69 / 45 = E     70 / 46 = F     71 / 47 = G     72 / 48 = H
 73 / 49 = I     74 / 4a = J     75 / 4b = K     76 / 4c = L
 77 / 4d = M     78 / 4e = N     79 / 4f = O     80 / 50 = P
 81 / 51 = Q     82 / 52 = R     83 / 53 = S     84 / 54 = T
 85 / 55 = U     86 / 56 = V     87 / 57 = W     88 / 58 = X
 89 / 59 = Y     90 / 5a = Z     91 / 5b = [     92 / 5c = \
 93 / 5d = ]     94 / 5e = ^     95 / 5f = _     96 / 60 = `
 97 / 61 = a     98 / 62 = b     99 / 63 = c    100 / 64 = d
101 / 65 = e    102 / 66 = f    103 / 67 = g    104 / 68 = h
105 / 69 = i    106 / 6a = j    107 / 6b = k    108 / 6c = l
109 / 6d = m    110 / 6e = n    111 / 6f = o    112 / 70 = p
113 / 71 = q    114 / 72 = r    115 / 73 = s    116 / 74 = t
117 / 75 = u    118 / 76 = v    119 / 77 = w    120 / 78 = x
121 / 79 = y    122 / 7a = z    123 / 7b = {    124 / 7c = |
125 / 7d = }    126 / 7e = ~    127 / 7f =     128 / 80 = Ç
129 / 81 = ü    130 / 82 = é    131 / 83 = â    132 / 84 = ä
133 / 85 = à    134 / 86 = å    135 / 87 = ç    136 / 88 = ê
137 / 89 = ë    138 / 8a = è    139 / 8b = ï    140 / 8c = î
141 / 8d = ì    142 / 8e = Ä    143 / 8f = Å    144 / 90 = É
145 / 91 = æ    146 / 92 = Æ    147 / 93 = ô    148 / 94 = ö
149 / 95 = ò    150 / 96 = û    151 / 97 = ù    152 / 98 = ÿ
153 / 99 = Ö    154 / 9a = Ü    155 / 9b = ø    156 / 9c = £
157 / 9d = Ø    158 / 9e = ×    159 / 9f = ƒ    160 / a0 = á
161 / a1 = í    162 / a2 = ó    163 / a3 = ú    164 / a4 = ñ
165 / a5 = Ñ    166 / a6 = ª    167 / a7 = º    168 / a8 = ¿
169 / a9 = ®    170 / aa = ¬    171 / ab = ½    172 / ac = ¼
173 / ad = ¡    174 / ae = «    175 / af = »    176 / b0 = ░
177 / b1 = ▒    178 / b2 = ▓    179 / b3 = │    180 / b4 = ┤
181 / b5 = Á    182 / b6 = Â    183 / b7 = À    184 / b8 = ©
185 / b9 = ╣    186 / ba = ║    187 / bb = ╗    188 / bc = ╝
189 / bd = ¢    190 / be = ¥    191 / bf = ┐    192 / c0 = └
193 / c1 = ┴    194 / c2 = ┬    195 / c3 = ├    196 / c4 = ─
197 / c5 = ┼    198 / c6 = ã    199 / c7 = Ã    200 / c8 = ╚
201 / c9 = ╔    202 / ca = ╩    203 / cb = ╦    204 / cc = ╠
205 / cd = ═    206 / ce = ╬    207 / cf = ¤    208 / d0 = ð
209 / d1 = Ð    210 / d2 = Ê    211 / d3 = Ë    212 / d4 = È
213 / d5 = ı    214 / d6 = Í    215 / d7 = Î    216 / d8 = Ï
217 / d9 = ┘    218 / da = ┌    219 / db = █    220 / dc = ▄
221 / dd = ¦    222 / de = Ì    223 / df = ▀    224 / e0 = Ó
225 / e1 = ß    226 / e2 = Ô    227 / e3 = Ò    228 / e4 = õ
229 / e5 = Õ    230 / e6 = µ    231 / e7 = þ    232 / e8 = Þ
233 / e9 = Ú    234 / ea = Û    235 / eb = Ù    236 / ec = ý
237 / ed = Ý    238 / ee = ¯    239 / ef = ´    240 / f0 = ­
241 / f1 = ±    242 / f2 = ‗    243 / f3 = ¾    244 / f4 = ¶
245 / f5 = §    246 / f6 = ÷    247 / f7 = ¸    248 / f8 = °
249 / f9 = ¨    250 / fa = ·    251 / fb = ¹    252 / fc = ³
253 / fd = ²    254 / fe = ■    255 / ff =
```

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? That is the reason he see two characters for one in his table. His table has completely different content that he thinks

Comment: @ Ryan B Read before comment. You do not have a clue what is happening there.

Comment: I ran the character test, and everything showed up as the same character for some reason... such as `32 / 20 = ╗`, `33 / 21 = ╗`, `34 / 22 = ╗` all the way to `255 / ff = ╗`

Comment: Forgot another i in my printf

Answer (score 0):

windows console used only Unicode (UTF-16 encoding) for display text in console. if you pass text to console in Unicode, say via `WriteConsoleW` - it will be displayed as is. if you use ansi version `WriteConsoleA` - your text initially will be converted to Unicode by call [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) and as first parameter `CodePage` will be used value returned from [`GetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp). by default console used OEM code page [`GetOEMCP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318114(v=vs.85).aspx). however you use ansi encoding ([`GetACP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx)). you can call [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp) before print in ansi. and you will be need use specific, hardcoded code page value - exactly the same, which your compiler use when compiled you source string `"▒▒██████▒▒"`. when you run on the same windows, where you compile code (*and if compiler not give you warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\uxxxx' cannot be represented in the current code page (N)*) - the `SetConsoleOutputCP(GetACP())` - will be worked, but the ANSI code pages can be different on different computers - so not work on another.

so good solution here - use Unicode `L"▒▒██████▒▒"` strings with `WriteConsoleW` or another `W` functions. if you got string in runtime as multibyte strings - you need before print it or
call `SetConsoleOutputCP(cp)` where cp - is code page used in your string and then use `A` function for output.
or (better) first yourself convert string to Unicode via `MultiByteToWideChar(cp, *)` and then use `W` functions for output

Comment: I changed `shade_block`'s type to `wchar_t`, added the L before it, and used wprintf, and now it prints nothing. Is this a problem with my compiler?

Comment: No. See my answer. Forget unicode & w_char for the moment.

Comment: @xaresys I use `WriteConsoleW` and it really print all this charasters

Comment: @PeterJ - why I need Forget unicode ? Unicode is native for windows and with Unicode all perfect working

Comment: @RbMm - calm down and give the guy a chance to go through his first "hello world" applications. I know that you know how to do it, but it will make a complete mess in his brain. Give him a chance to understand what the string, pointer etc etc are. I hope that you know what I mean

Comment: @xaresys - `wprintf` not solution here, because look like crt translate Unicode to ansi first (with own default code page convertions) and then use ansi `printf` - problem with crt itself. use windows api `WriteConsoleW` instead. with this all is worked.